# How to change git pack files permissions in remote

Tags: bash, git, kubernetes, dockerfile

I have a peculiar situation to copy the entire repos to a Kubernetes pod, this is the config for our spring boot application, pack files copy causing failure and eventually, the docker container is failing to start

```
$ ls -lh
total 776
-rw-r--r--  1 sunil adms 41K 12 Jan 18:34 pack-27a9d...fbae25e368e4cf.idx
-rw-r--r--  1 sunil adms 343K 12 Jan 18:34 pack-27a9d...fb5e368e4cf.pack
```

The error below causes the container startup failure assuming that this is a blocker, where in this is not at all required at the moment.

ERROR:

```
Error:

cp: cannot create regular file '/data/./.git/objects/pack/pack-27a9d...fb5e368e4cf.pack': Permission denied

cp: cannot create regular file '/data/./.git/objects/pack/pack-27a9d...fbae25e368e4cf.idx': Permission denied
```

I am looking for 2 options here:

1. Change these file permissions and then store them in the remote with rwx permissions
2. Do something to the docker file to ignore this script failure error and start the container.

Docker file which issues this script execution

`ENTRYPOINT ["sh","config-update-force.sh","|| true"]`

Comment: Is this the same as [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75100251/docker-container-unable-to-ignore-the-entrypoint-bash-script-failure), which has many more details about what the script does?  If it's different, can you [edit] this question to include a [mcve], with more details than just the filename of the script?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your issue as the information provided is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

if needed, in your yaml manifest try updating permissions of the user who runs it with securityContext as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  containers:
  # specification of the pod's containers
  # ...
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
```