# Docker container unable to ignore the EntryPoint bash script failure

Tags: bash, docker, kubernetes

Bash script:

```
clonePath=/data/config/
git branch -r | fgrep -v 'origin/HEAD' | sed 's|  origin/|git checkout |' > checkoutAllBranches.sh
chmod +x checkoutAllBranches.sh
echo "Fetch branch: `cat checkoutAllBranches.sh`"
./checkoutAllBranches.sh
git checkout master
git remote rm origin
rm checkoutAllBranches.sh

for config_dir in `ls -a`; do
  cp -r $config_dir $clonePath/;
done

echo "API Config update complete..."
```

Dockerfile which issues this script execution

`ENTRYPOINT ["sh","config-update-force.sh","|| true"]`

The error below causes the container startup failure despite setting the command status to 0 manually using || true

ERROR:

```
Error:

cp: cannot create regular file '/data/./.git/objects/pack/pack-27a9d...fb5e368e4cf.pack': Permission denied

cp: cannot create regular file '/data/./.git/objects/pack/pack-27a9d...fbae25e368e4cf.idx': Permission denied
```

I am looking for 2 options here:

1. Change these file permissions and then store them in the remote with rwx permissions
2. Do something to the docker file to ignore this script failure error and start the container.

DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM docker.hub.com/java11-temurin:latest
USER root
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y rsync telnet vim wget git
RUN mkdir -p /opt/config/clone/data
RUN chown -R 1001:1001 /opt/config
USER 1001
ADD build/libs/my-api-config-server.jar .
ADD config-update-force.sh .
USER root
RUN chmod +x config-update-force.sh
USER 1001
EXPOSE 8080
CMD java $BASE_JAVA_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS -jar my-api-config-server.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","config-update-force.sh","|| true"]
```

BASH SCRIPT:

```
#!/bin/bash

set +e
set +x

clonePath=/opt/clone/data/data

#source Optumfile.properties
echo "properties loaded: example ${git_host}"

if [ -d my-api-config ]; then
  rm -rf my-api-config;
  echo "existing my-api-config dir deleted..."
fi

git_url=https://github.com/my-api-config-server
git clone https://github.com/my-api-config-server
cd my-api-config-server
git branch -r | fgrep -v 'origin/HEAD' | sed 's|  origin/|git checkout |' > checkoutAllBranches.sh
chmod +x checkoutAllBranches.sh
echo "Fetch branch: `cat checkoutAllBranches.sh`"
./checkoutAllBranches.sh
git checkout master
git remote rm origin
rm checkoutAllBranches.sh

for config_dir in `ls -a`; do
  cp -r $config_dir $clonePath/;
done

echo "My API Config update complete..."
```

Comment: Can you please post the script itself? Using `|| true` is not the worst solution, by the way. If the step is indeed optional, why not ignore the error.

Comment: I've updated the script @lxg, and one more thing please, the script is fine, I mean i am good with the error, if I run the same script manually in the pod I get the same permission denied but that wont impact anything, no harm, but during the container startup it is unable to continue assuming that it is a blocker, I am trying to make the container ignore this error

Comment: Where does `$clonePath` come from?

Comment: sorry, as this is my company code and i have restrictions in posting them, I trimmed it down and missed this variable, clone path is /data/config

Comment: Makes sense. As mentioned above, using `|| true` seems like an appropriate fix here; however, I think that a root cause analysis would yield something related to either the permissions of the target directory. But you’d have to share much more data for this to explore which I understand is not an option here.

Comment: sure, let me share enough data @Ixg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251088/discussion-between-sunil-nagavelli-and-lxg).

Answer (score 0):

When you do in the script...

```
chmod +x checkoutAllBranches.sh
```

...than why not before `cp`

```
chmod -R +rwx ${clonePath}
```

...or if the `stderr` message 'wont impact anything'...

```
cp -r $config_dir $clonePath/ 2>/dev/null;
```

...even `cp` dont copy `-v`erbosly.
?

Comment: The only issue is with the cp command that you mentioned last, what happens is that during the copy, there are these files under the .git folder in which I am unable to change file permissions and when copying them I get a permission denied error, it works well directly in the pod, but docker container during the startup thinks it as a failed command and stops running.

I was thinking about this option `cp -r $config_dir $clonePath/ 2>/dev/null;
` earlier @koyaanisqatsi, does this make the permission denied error ignored and make the container run?

Comment: It only dont put out the ```cp: cannot create regular file``` Errors. - ```cp```' Returncode of ```!=0``` will stay.

Comment: Yeah, I just checked this and unfortunately `cp -r $config_dir $clonePath/ 2>/dev/null;` did not work @koyaanisqatsi

Comment: So what User/Group should have the Owner of the Script to have the rights for doing that? - ( User/Group of ```clonePath``` ) - Maybe you reach that with ```sudo```?

Comment: sadly sudo is now allowed @koyaanisqatsi, else i would have not seen this issue in the script execution...

Comment: So your problem is to get the Permissions. It has to be run as normal User right? - And last time i ask this: What User/Group has ```clonePath```? Because if it is 0/0 (root.root) than there is no other way than ```sudo``` on the other Hand it is easy for root.root to do ```su -l username -c 'iamrunningasnormaluser.sh'```

Comment: Did you have try the ```|| true``` "ignore" Tip from starting post comments? - Try in the for loop: ```cp -r $config_dir $clonePath/ || true```

Answer (score 0):

When your Dockerfile declares an `ENTRYPOINT`, that command is the *only* thing the container does.  If it also declares a `CMD`, [the `CMD` is passed as additional arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact); it is not run on its own unless the `ENTRYPOINT` makes sure to execute it.

Shell errors are not normally fatal, and especially if you explicitly `set +e`, even if a shell command fails the shell script will keep running.  You see this in your output where you get multiple `cp` errors; the first error does not terminate the script.

You need to do two things here.  The first is to set the `ENTRYPOINT` to actually run the `CMD`; the simplest and most common way to do this is to end the script with

```bash
exec "$@"
```

The second is to remove the `|| true` from the Dockerfile.  As you have it written out currently, this is passed as the first argument to the entrypoint wrapper – it is not run through a shell and it is not interpreted as a "or" operator.  If your script begins with a "shebang" line and is marked executable (both of these are correct in the question) the you do not explicitly need the `sh` interpreter.

```bash
# must be a JSON array; no additional "|| true" argument; no sh -c wrapper
ENTRYPOINT ["./config-update-force.sh"]

# any valid CMD will work with `exec "$@"
CMD java $BASE_JAVA_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS -jar my-api-config-server.jar
```